# woocommerce custom filtered product page crafting, or how to correctly patch wp_query in woocommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

it is required, that custom url like /catalog/category/subcategory/my_mark/ displayed products of this subcategory (filtered for my_mark presense) exactly as it would be in case of /catalog/category/subcategory/.
I wrote a plugin and tried to conditionally change the logic by changing $wp_query variable in functions as:

```
load_template, get_header
```

but still, it is not the same template order, so the question is how (and/or where) to change the $wp_query just to show the results in right template order, as it would be in normal subcategory template view ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did it via filtering template_include function, previously debugged the correct template file used. here's the code, maybe it will help someone:

```
add_filter('template_include', 'seo_includer' );
function seo_includer($args) {

        global $wp_query;

        if(<my_condition>)
        {
            if (true) {
                status_header( 200 );
                $wp_query->is_404=false;
            }

            $args = array(
                'posts_per_page' => 777,
                'product_cat' => $category['slug'],
                'post_type' => 'product',
                'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
            );
            $wp_query = new WP_Query($args);
            return ABSPATH.'wp-content/themes/<mytheme>/woocommerce/taxonomy-product_cat.php';
        }
        return $args;
}
```